# How can i read from two text files and write to one text file

Tags: java

I have written a basic practice program that will read an even and old text files... after that i want my program to write to another textfile named both.txt. i want this both.txt file to containt data from both the even and old text files but after writing my code as shown bwlow, it is only writting the old text file to it rather than taking both files even and old!

How can i go about it?

Below is my code

```
package files;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Files {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
    Scanner thoko = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose the file you want to write to:");
        
    int number = thoko.nextInt();
    switch (number){
        case 1:
            try{
                File even = new File("even.txt");
                even.createNewFile();

                PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("even.txt"));

                for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                    if(i%2==0){
                        write.print(i+",");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Writting to an even text file is a succes");
                write.close();
                
                
            }
            
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("Error opening the file even.txt");
                    System.exit(0);
                }   break;
                
        case 2:
            try{
                File old = new File("old.txt");
                old.createNewFile();

                PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("old.txt"));

                for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                    if(i%2==1){
                        write.print(i+",");`
`
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Writting to an old text file is a succes");
                write.close();
                

            }
            
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("Error opening the file old.txt");
                    System.exit(0);
                }   break;
                
        case 3:
            try{
                FileReader me = new FileReader("even.txt");
                FileReader ne = new FileReader("old.txt");
                
                FileWriter de = new FileWriter("both.txt");
                
                String str = "";
                int i;
                
                while ((i = me.read())!=-1 && (i = ne.read())!=-1){
                    str +=(char)i;
                }
                System.out.println("Writting to both file done");
                de.write(str);
                
                
                me.close();
                ne.close();
                de.close();
                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("Error opening the file old.txt");
                    System.exit(0);
                }   break;
            }
            
            }
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((i = me.read())!=-1 && (i = ne.read())!=-1){
```

Here you set `i` to `me.read()` and then immediatly overwrite it to `ne.read()`. Consequently, only `ne.read()` gets written in the loop body.